# Ran a test on my code and received an unexpected answer

Tags: java

I am trying to get the expected result from Test 3 in the image below. Can someone point me in the right way to be able to solve it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class TwoNumbers here.
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class TwoNumbers
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter two numbers (like this: 41.7 -22.5): ");
        Double number1 =  input.nextDouble();
        Double number2 = input.nextDouble();

        if(number1 == number2)
        {
            System.out.println("The first number is equal to the second");
        }

        else if(number1 > number2)
        {
            System.out.println("The First number is greater than second");
        }

        else
        {
            if(number1 < number2)
            System.out.println("The first number is less than second");
        }

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: `number1 == number2` => this is old known Java "trap" when comparing primitive wrapper classes (checking their reference instead of value), use `equals` method instead.

Answer (score 5):

You're autoboxing `double`s to `java.lang.Double`s, which would be equal, but probably won't use the exact same reference.

You should either use primitive `double`s:

```
double number1 = input.nextDouble();
double number2 = input.nextDouble();
```

Or, if you're using `java.lang.Double`s, compare them using the `equals` method:,

```
if (number1.equals(number2))
{
    System.out.println("The first number is equal to the second");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare if two object non-primitive are equals you should use  `.equals()` instead of `==`

```
if(number1.equals(number2)){
    System.out.println("The first number is equal to the second");
}
```